# Is resulting `insertedIds` unordered when insertMany() with ordered=False?

Tags: mongodb, insert, bulkinsert

Official documentation of `insertMany()` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/ as per Jan 2022 states about using `ordered=false`

> If ordered is set to false, documents are inserted in an unordered format and may be
> reordered by mongod to increase performance. Applications should not depend on ordering of inserts if using an unordered insertMany().

All text in that page is explicit about the documents will be inserted in an unordered format which can have forseable effects on the generated ids distribution, but it is not explicit about the `insertedIds` field in the return value. So, assuming a successful operation are they unordered too? or can I reliably assign the resulting Id to each inserted document?

Comment: The _id is the mandatory field for each document in a collection - its like a primary key. It's value is unique and is immutable. If you dont provide the _id value for a document, MongoDB inserts the value of type ObjectId. The ordering of insertions is for the documents.

Comment: your comment is still not explicit to the returning ids, are they unordered too? or they can be zipped to the documents saved?